# How to call api.stopEditing(true) from cellRender custom component to notify ag-grid component

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have created a custom component class for **CheckBox** render and from there I want to notify the parent class that cell editing happens and needs to call `api.stopEditing(true);` but its never get called please check the below code.

Custome Render Class for CheckBox:

```
export class AgGridCheckboxComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  private params: any;

  checked: boolean = false;

  agInit(params: any): void {
      this.params = params;
      this.checked = this.params.value === "Approved";
  }

  // demonstrates how you can do "inline" editing of a cell
  onChange(checked: boolean) {
    // console.log("CheckBox value:",this.params.value)
      this.checked = checked;
      this.params.node.setDataValue(this.params.colDef, this.checked ? "Approved" : "");
      this.params.value = this.checked ? "Approved" : "";
      if (this.params.eGridCell) {
          this.params.eGridCell.focus();
      }
      this.params.api.stopEditing(true);
  }

  refresh(params: any): boolean {
      return true;
  }
}
```

above line `this.params.api.stopEditing(true);` never notify my parent class where I added listener for stopEditing.

My Listener in Parent class:

```
 onCellEditingStopped: function (event) {
        console.log('onCellEditingStopped',event);
        self.updateProductValue(event.value,event.rowIndex,event.colDef.field);
      }
```

Help me to call `stopEditing(true)` manually from custom class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a child component notify its parent about something happening in the child component, you will have to use @Output:
first you declare a property in your child component like so:

```
@Output() stopEdit = new EventEmitter();
```

then you fire the event from where you want inside you child component again, I believe you want to fire it inside onChange, like so:

```
onChange(checked: boolean) {
  // your code
  this.stopEdit.emit(true);
}
```

and finally you listen to the event in your parent component:

```
<ag-grid-checkbox (stopEdit)="onCellEditingStopped($event)"></ag-grid-checkbox>
```

Comment: it's not child to parent update its a case of ag-grid framework where I want an event which will notify to ag-grid which is added in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox, the onCellValueChange is not getting fired when it changes.
But you can try using onCellClicked to notify the parent and check if it is the checkbox column.
You can do something like this -

```
onCellClicked:(event) => {
      if(event.colDef.field === 'cbox'){
        self.updateProductValue(event.value,event.rowIndex,event.colDef.field);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this will work if my checkbox is in the same class but I created one custom class fro check box from there I need to update it to ag-grid with calling stopEditing() let me know if it make any sence?

Comment: Yes, this will trigger even when you have a custom cell renderer.No need to call stopEditing(), the changes will be notified in the parent component.

Comment: as I mention in my question I haven't used the default ag-grid checkbox I created my custom class for checkbox and from there I want to call stopEditing() your above code is for default checkbox which ag-grid provides.

Comment: The onCellClicked will trigger even when you use a custom checkbox.